# App crashes in Instruments only

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-instruments

Our app runs fine. In Instruments (on the simulator), when trying to profile memory, under Allocations I see Overall Bytes rising very fast, while Live Bytes remain small. There are no leaks and VM usage seems stable (if large).

This is not a show-stopper, but makes profiling that much more difficult. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Same problem here ! it is crashing and showing error on wired line like notification posting etc .